# How to set default devices for sis creation

Tags: symbian, carbide, symbian3

An error occured during sis creation via command window. Which says:

> "To use new symbian OS tools specify a default device using devices
>   -setdefault(otherwise unset EPOCROOT and specify a device explicitly)"

Answer (score 0):

Set your EPOCROOT variable.

If your environment is at something like: `C:\Nokia\devices\Nokia_Symbian3_SDK_v1.0\`

Then on your command line call:

`set EPOCROOT=\Nokia\devices\Nokia_Symbian3_SDK_v1.0\`

Or set it in your environment variables.

Note the drive letter is omitted and it ends with a slash.

---

To set a default devices, first check what you have installed with the `devices` command, for example:

```
C:\Nokia\devices\Nokia_Symbian3_SDK_v1.0\>devices
Nokia_Symbian3_SDK_v1.0:com.nokia.symbian
S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0:com.nokia.s60 - default
```

If I wanted to change it to make the S^3 SDK default, use `devices -setdefault @deviceID`:

```
C:\Nokia\devices\Nokia_Symbian3_SDK_v1.0\>devices -setdefault @Nokia_Symbian3_SDK_v1.0:com.nokia.symbian
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the following in the xml and it worked

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Symbian\devices.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <devices version="1.0">
        <device id="Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0" name="com.nokia.symbian" default="yes" userdeletable="yes">
            <epocroot>C:\Nokia\devices\Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0</epocroot>
            <toolsroot>C:\Nokia\devices\Nokia_Symbian_Belle_SDK_v1.0</toolsroot>
        </device>
   </devices>
```